# Formal alternative for "like" and "such as"?

Tags: synonyms, formality

Is there a more formal way of saying:

"In most western countries, such as the United States, an increased level of ... has been observed."

Or should such a sentence be rephrased completely?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The phrase "such as" *is* a formal phrase, and as such, you should feel free to use it in formal writing. (The informal equivalent would be "like": *Places **like** the US have seen an increase in...*)

Comment: You can use "like" in formal writing as well. "Painters like Monet, who were concerned with capturing the evanescent impressions of light, were dubbed Impressionists." Where you would *not* use "like" is as a substitute for *as*: "As [not like] I mentioned earlier, Monet and his contemporaries were called Impressionists."

Comment: In @JSBangs's answer, 'such as' introduces an example. In @Robusto's comment, 'like' means *Monet and other painters similar to him*. There is a subtle difference as when we use 'such as' the way JSBangs has, the other examples might not share similarities with the selected one.

Answer (score 10):

Some alternatives include:

- for example
- for instance

There is a subtle difference between 'such as' and 'like'.

> Most western countries, such as the US...

Means

> Most western countries, with the US being an example...

On the other hand

> Most western countries like the US...

Could be interpreted as

> Most western countries that are similar to the US

Which may not be what you mean.

Comment: I agree with your "such as" example, but not with your "like" example. I think that the comma makes it clear that the reader should interpret the US as an example and not a prerequisite. Without the comma, *“Most western countries like the US…”* I would be more likely to interpret it as a prerequisite (that are similar to…). In contrast, the comma can be removed from your "such as" example and the meaning would still be retained either way.

Comment: @chharvey >6 years later, I'm rereading this and am inclined to agree with you. Thus, I've made an edit.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about formality, but if you want to capitalise on the residual popularity of Miss Teen USA 2007 then you could do worse than follow the wonderful precedent set by [Miss South Carolina](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lj3iNxZ8Dww), who responded to the question

> “Recent polls have shown that a fifth of Americans can’t locate the US on a world map. Why do you think this is?”

with (emphasis added)...

> I personally believe, that U.S. Americans,
>   are unable to do so,
>   because uh,
>   some, people out there, in our nation don’t have maps.
>   and uh…
>   I believe that our education ***like such as*** in South Africa,
>   and the Iraq,
>   everywhere ***like such as***…
>   and, I believe they should uh,
>   our education over here,
>   in the U.S. should help the U.S.
>   or should help South Africa,
>   and should help the Iraq and Asian countries so we will be able to build up our future,
>   for our [children].”

Answer (score 0):

On the "rephrase completely" note, I would consider taking the center clause out:

> In most western countries, an
>   increased level of ... has been
>   observed

The U.S. is now pretty much the archetype western country, so you're not providing additional information.  If you want to emphasize the U.S. is included, then you could use:

> In most western countries, including
>   the United States, an increased level
>   of ... has been observed